# Fortify throws error while scanning Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, fortify

I'm trying to run Fortify on a Visual Studio 2008 project. The project builds successfully on its own. When I try to analyze the project with Fortify using the Visual Studio integrated controls, the project builds successfully but an error message is thrown. Here's the output from Fortify console:

```
Fortify SCA...
Running: "-show-runtime-properties" 
Running: "-b" "ProjectName" "-clean" 
Error setting VCProject Path. Abort VC project related scan
Scan Failed Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<string here>' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
   at FortifyBase.Scanner.CPPScanUtil.ResetVCProjectExecutableDirectories()
   at FortifyCommon.Scanner.BuildListeners.VSBuildDone(vsBuildScope scope, vsBuildAction action)
Scan Failed: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<string here>' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

When I run Fortify from the standalone Audit Workbench, I get the following error message:

```
SCA Commandline invocation failed
[error]: Build ID "ProjectName" doesn't exist.
```

I keep most of the default scan options except changing 'Is this a J2EE web application' to 'No' (I also tried leaving this to 'yes' but that didn't work either.

Searching for any info on the error messages only produced another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161101/fortify-source-analyzer-and-apache-lenya) on Stack Overflow but the project setup seems quite different from my Visual Studio project. Anyways, I also tried running the scan from command line with the arguments provided by Visual Studio but I get the same error message.

Fortify documentation mentions that the build ID is used to track which files are compiled and linked as part of a build and later to scan those files and that it is usually the project name. I tried a few different strings as the build ID but nothing seems to work.

Anyone has any idea where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Update**: The problem occurs during the translate phase of the analysis due to which the build ID is not created at all. Here's the log from the sourceanalyzer log:

```
[2010-08-23 21:20:53 INFO]
Fortify Source Code Analyzer 5.1.0.0061
[2010-08-23 21:20:53 INFO]
Args:
["-b", "ProjectName", "-machine-output", "-vsversion", "8.0", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe", "ProjectName.sln", "/rebuild", "DEBUG"]
[2010-08-23 21:20:53 INFO]
VM Args:
"-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=100 -Xss1M -Xmx600M -Xms16M"
[2010-08-23 21:21:04 INFO 1102]
Compiler execution failed (exit code: 1).
[2010-08-23 21:21:04 WARNING]
exit(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think this is a known issue with C/C++ translation on VS2010.  The workaround I found is:

1. Open a Visual Studio x86 Command Prompt
2. Change to the KindleExport.sln's directory
3. Run:
   sourceanalyzer -b kindleexport devenv KindleExport.sln /REBUILD
4. Run:
   sourceanalyzer -b kindleexport -scan -f KindleExport.fpr