# Is Visual Studio required to run Fortify on .net sources?

Tags: visual-studio, fortify

Is Visual Studio required to be installed on the machine if I want to run Fortify (from command line) on .net sources? I am trying to run fortify from command line but its always complaining about Build Id does not exist.

Thanks,
Tara Singh

Answer (score 2):

Tara, SCA for .NET requires the .NET compiler for translation purposes. You can download the SDK which includes the compilers and the core DLLs from Microsoft for free.

Can you include the commands you issued?

Comment: Hi Flee,this is the command I am running :   "-b" "MyProj" "-machine-output" "-scan" "-f" "C:\..\Scan.fpr" "-format" "fpr"

Answer (score 0):

See this link:
[Fortify throws error while scanning Visual Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545887/fortify-throws-error-while-scanning-visual-studio-project)

Not sure if this is a solution to your issue.

Taken from Fortify [Support Website](https://www.fortify.com/support/index.html):

---

- Web Support

Receive Web Support by logging into Fortify [Self-Service](http://support.fortify.com/). Here you can:

- Submit a New Ticket
- Manage Existing Tickets
- Search the Knowledge Base

---

- Email Support

Contact Fortify Technical Support by email at `techsupport@fortify.com`.

Comment: I already saw this page, the first step is "Open a Visual Studio x86 Command Prompt" and i do not have VS installed and I do not want to install VS if it is only used for running Fortify.

Comment: In that case, check my answer again - I just edited it to include contact instructions for contacting their tech support.

Comment: Already contacted them. waiting for any help. Thanks for help .

Comment: Tara: Did you ever get any clarification? I'm running a number of scans, so am having the developers send me the debug output of builds to scan (since I don't have VS on the scan box)

Answer (score 0):

[Michael Hidalgo](http://blog.michaelhidalgo.info/) talk about this in his blog post dated Sep 2,2013
http://blog.michaelhidalgo.info/2013/09/configuring-ildasmexe-in-hp-fortify.html

> **Configuring ILDASM.exe in HP Fortify (when Visual Studio .Net is not
>   installed)**
>
> I was trying to use HP fortify to scan a ASP.NET Web application, but
>   I realized that I did not have Visual Studio or the Windows SDK.
>
> HP Fortify requires ildasm.exe to perform the scan. Due the fact I was
>   not able to do a full installation of Visual Studio .Net because of
>   disk space, I just installed Windows SDK, which will also install
>   ildasm.
>
> Once installed, the problem  still remains. HP fortify will try to
>   locate ildasm.exe in a default path (which I was not able to figure
>   out what was). Fortunately, using HP Fortify you can specify the path
>   of ildasm.exe.
>
> We need to locate the fortify-sca.properties (which is a kind of
>   configuration file). This file can be found in the following path
>   C:\Program Files\HP_Fortify\HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_3.90\Core\config.
>
> A new key is required com.fortify.sca.IldasmPath
>
> This is the path where ildasm.exe resides  in my current installation:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\ildasm.exe
>
> Note that we need to scape the backslash (\).
>   [image]